# Can someone explain the traverse function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, traversal

I am trying and failing to grok the `traverse` function from `Data.Traversable`. I am unable to see its point. Since I come from an imperative background, can someone please explain it to me in terms of an imperative loop? Pseudo-code would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The article [The Essence of the Iterator Pattern](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf) might be helpful as it builds the notion of traverse step by step. Some advanced concepts are present though

Answer (score 135):

`traverse` is the same as `fmap`, except that it also allows you to run effects while you're rebuilding the data structure.

Take a look at the example from the `Data.Traversable` documentation.

```
 data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

The `Functor` instance of `Tree` would be:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f Empty        = Empty
  fmap f (Leaf x)     = Leaf (f x)
  fmap f (Node l k r) = Node (fmap f l) (f k) (fmap f r)
```

It rebuilds the entire tree, applying `f` to every value.

```
instance Traversable Tree where
    traverse f Empty        = pure Empty
    traverse f (Leaf x)     = Leaf <$> f x
    traverse f (Node l k r) = Node <$> traverse f l <*> f k <*> traverse f r
```

The `Traversable` instance is almost the same, except the constructors are called in applicative style. This means that we can have (side-)effects while rebuilding the tree. Applicative is almost the same as monads, except that effects cannot depend on previous results. In this example it means that you could not do something different to the right branch of a node depending on the results of rebuilding the left branch for example.

For historical reasons, the `Traversable` class also contains a monadic version of `traverse` called `mapM`. For all intents and purposes `mapM` is the same as `traverse` - it exists as a separate method because `Applicative` only later became a superclass of `Monad`.

If you would implement this in an impure language, `fmap` would be the same as `traverse`, as there is no way to prevent side-effects. You can't implement it as a loop, as you have to traverse your data structure recursively. Here's a small example how I would do it in Javascript:

```
Node.prototype.traverse = function (f) {
  return new Node(this.l.traverse(f), f(this.k), this.r.traverse(f));
}
```

Implementing it like this limits you to the effects that the language allows though. If you f.e. want non-determinism (which the list instance of Applicative models) and your language doesn't have it built-in, you're out of luck.

Comment: What does the term 'effect' mean?

Comment: @missingfaktor: It means the structural information of a `Functor`, the part that's not parametric. The state value in `State`, failure in `Maybe` and `Either`, the number of elements in `[]`, and of course arbitrary external side effects in `IO`. I don't care for it as a generic term (like the `Monoid` functions using "empty" and "append", the concept is more generic than the term suggests at first) but it's fairly common and serves the purpose well enough.

Comment: @missingfaktor : in Landei's answer the effect is "throwing an exception" by returning Nothing

Comment: "I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to do this [...]." Definitely not -- it would be as nasty as making the effects of `ap` depend on the previous results. I have reworded that remark accordingly.

Comment: `mapM` should always do the same thing as `traverse`. I've removed the example from the answer.

Comment: _"Applicative is almost the same as monads, except that effects cannot depend on previous results."_ ... a lot of stuff clicked into place for me with this line, thanks!

Comment: @missingfaktor  Great explanation of "effect,", indeed the missing factor not elsewhere explained so clearly.

Answer (score 69):

`traverse` turns things inside a `Traversable` into a `Traversable` of things "inside" an `Applicative`, given a function that makes `Applicative`s out of things.

Let's use `Maybe` as `Applicative` and list as `Traversable`. First we need the transformation function:

```
half x = if even x then Just (x `div` 2) else Nothing
```

So if a number is even, we get half of it (inside a `Just`), else we get `Nothing`. If everything goes "well", it looks like this:

```
traverse half [2,4..10]
--Just [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But...

```
traverse half [1..10]
-- Nothing
```

The reason is that the `<*>` function is used to build the result, and when one of the arguments is `Nothing`, we get `Nothing` back.

Another example:

```
rep x = replicate x x
```

This function generates a list of length `x` with the content `x`, e.g. `rep 3` = `[3,3,3]`. What is the result of `traverse rep [1..3]`?

We get the partial results of `[1]`, `[2,2]` and `[3,3,3]` using `rep`. Now the semantics of lists as `Applicatives` is "take all combinations", e.g. `(+) <$> [10,20] <*> [3,4]` is `[13,14,23,24]`.

"All combinations" of `[1]` and `[2,2]` are two times `[1,2]`. All combinations of two times `[1,2]` and `[3,3,3]` are six times `[1,2,3]`. So we have:

```
traverse rep [1..3]
--[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: You end result reminds me of [this](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html).

Comment: @missingno: Yeah, they missed `fac n = length $ traverse rep [1..n]`

Comment: Actually, its there under "List-encoding-programmer" (but using list comprehensions). That website is *comprehensive* :)

Comment: @missingno: Hm, it's not *exactly* the same... both are relying on the list monad's Cartesian product behavior, but the site only uses two at a time, so it's more like doing `liftA2 (,)` than the more generic form using `traverse`.

Comment: `> transpose [[1],[2,2],[3,3,3]]`  is `[[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]` or `tails` and `> transpose [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` is `[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]`

Answer (score 45):

I think it's easiest to understand in terms of `sequenceA`, as `traverse` can be defined as
follows.

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
traverse f = sequenceA . fmap f
```

`sequenceA` sequences together the elements of a structure from left to right, returning a structure with the same shape containing the results.

```
sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
sequenceA = traverse id
```

You can also think of `sequenceA` as reversing the order of two functors, e.g. going from a list of actions into an action returning a list of results.

So `traverse` takes some structure, and applies `f` to transform every element in the structure into some applicative, it then sequences up the effects of those applicatives from left to right, returning a structure with the same shape containing the results.

You can also compare it to `Foldable`, which defines the related function `traverse_`.

```
traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()
```

So you can see that the key difference between `Foldable` and `Traversable` is that the latter allows you to preserve the shape of the structure, whereas the former requires you to fold the result up into some other value.

---

A simple example of its usage is using a list as the traversable structure, and `IO` as the applicative:

```
λ> import Data.Traversable
λ> let qs = ["name", "quest", "favorite color"]
λ> traverse (\thing -> putStrLn ("What is your " ++ thing ++ "?") *> getLine) qs
What is your name?
Sir Lancelot
What is your quest?
to seek the holy grail
What is your favorite color?
blue
["Sir Lancelot","to seek the holy grail","blue"]
```

While this example is rather unexciting, things get more interesting when `traverse` is used on other types of containers, or using other applicatives.

Comment: So traverse is simply a more general form of mapM? In fact, `sequenceA . fmap` for lists is equivalent to `sequence .  map` isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sequencing side effects' ? What is 'side effect' in your answer - I just thought that side effects are possible only in monads. Regards.

Comment: @Marek "I just thought that side effects are possible only in monads" -- The connection is much looser than that: (1) The `IO` *type* can be used to express side effects; (2) `IO` happens to be a monad, which turns out to be very convenient. Monads are not essentially linked to side effects. It should also be noted that there is a meaning of "effect" which is broader than "side effect" in its usual sense -- one which include pure computations. On this last point, see also [*What exactly does “effectful” mean*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33386622/2751851).

Comment: (By the way, @hammar, I took the liberty to change "side effect" to "effect" in this answer due to the reasons outlined in the comment above.)

Answer (score 22):

It's kind of like `fmap`, except that you can run effects inside the mapper function, which also changes the result type.

Imagine a list of integers representing user IDs in a database: `[1, 2, 3]`. If you want to `fmap` these user IDs to usernames, you can't use a traditional `fmap`, because inside the function you need to access the database to read the usernames (which requires an effect -- in this case, using the `IO` monad).

The signature of `traverse` is:

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

With `traverse`, you can do effects, therefore, your code for mapping user IDs to usernames looks like:

```
mapUserIDsToUsernames :: (Num -> IO String) -> [Num] -> IO [String]
mapUserIDsToUsernames fn ids = traverse fn ids
```

---

There's also a function called `mapM`:

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
```

Any use of `mapM` can be replaced with `traverse`, but not the other way around. `mapM` only works for monads, whereas `traverse` is more generic.

If you just want to achieve an effect and not return any useful value, there are `traverse_` and `mapM_` versions of these functions, both of which ignore the return value from the function and are slightly faster.

Comment: I have tweaked your answer [for the same reasons that led me to edit hammar's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460809/can-someone-explain-the-traverse-function-in-haskell/7460846#comment86379664_7460846).

Answer (score 7):

`traverse` *is* the loop. Its implementation depends on the data structure to be traversed. That might be a list, tree, `Maybe`, `Seq`(uence), or anything that has a generic way of being traversed via something like a for-loop or recursive function. An array would have a for-loop, a list a while-loop, a tree either something recursive or the combination of a stack with a while-loop; but in functional languages you do not need these cumbersome loop commands: you combine the inner part of the loop (in the shape of a function) with the data structure in a more directly manner and less verbose.

With the `Traversable` typeclass, you could probably write your algorithms more independent and versatile. But my experience says, that `Traversable` is usually only used to simply glue algorithms to existing data structures. It is quite nice not to need to write similar functions for different datatypes qualified, too.