# Agda: parse a string with numbers

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I am trying to parse a string with natural numbers in Agda.
e.g., the result of `stringListToℕ "1,2,3"` should be `Just (1 ∷ 2  ∷ 3 ∷ [])`

My current code is not quite right or by any means nice, but it works.
However it returns the type:
    `Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ))`

The Question is:

1. How to implement the function `stringListToℕ` in a nice way (compared to my code);
   it should have the type `Maybe (List ℕ)`
2. (optional, not important) How can I convert the type `Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ))` to `Maybe (List ℕ)`?

My Code:

```
charToℕ : Char → Maybe ℕ
charToℕ '0' = just 0
charToℕ '1' = just 1
charToℕ '2' = just 2
charToℕ '3' = just 3
charToℕ '4' = just 4
charToℕ '5' = just 5
charToℕ '6' = just 6
charToℕ '7' = just 7
charToℕ '8' = just 8
charToℕ '9' = just 9
charToℕ _   = nothing

stringToℕ' : List Char → (acc : ℕ) → Maybe ℕ 
stringToℕ' []       acc = just acc
stringToℕ' (x ∷ xs) acc = charToℕ x >>= λ n → stringToℕ' xs ( 10 * acc + n )

stringToℕ : String → Maybe ℕ
stringToℕ s = stringToℕ' (toList s) 0 

isComma : Char → Bool
isComma h = h Ch.== ','

notComma : Char → Bool
notComma ',' = false
notComma _ = true 

{-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}
split : List Char → List (List Char)
split [] = []
split s = l ∷ split (drop (length(l) + 1) s)
    where l : List Char
          l = takeWhile notComma s

isNothing' : Maybe ℕ → Bool
isNothing' nothing = true
isNothing' _       = false

isNothing : List (Maybe ℕ) → Bool 
isNothing l = any isNothing' l

-- wrong type, should be String -> Maybe (List N)
stringListToℕ : String → Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ))
stringListToℕ s = if (isNothing res) then nothing else just res
              where res : List (Maybe ℕ)
                    res = map stringToℕ (map fromList( split (Data.String.toList s)))

test1 = stringListToℕ "1,2,3"
-- => just (just 1 ∷ just 2 ∷ just 3 ∷ [])
```

**EDIT**

I tried to write a conversion function using `from-just`, but this gives a error when type checking:

```
  conv : Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ)) → Maybe (List ℕ) 
  conv (just xs) = map from-just xs
  conv _ = nothing
```

the error is:

```
Cannot instantiate the metavariable _143 to solution
(Data.Maybe.From-just (_145 xs) x) since it contains the variable x
which is not in scope of the metavariable or irrelevant in the
metavariable but relevant in the solution
when checking that the expression from-just has type
Maybe (_145 xs) → _143 xs
```

Comment: In Haskell there's `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]`. If Agda doesn't have it, you can take a look at its implementation [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence).

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher: Agda does have it, it's in `Data.List`.

Comment: thanks for the comments! I tried to map "from-just" on the list, but this doesn't work either (which I expected somehow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took the liberty of rewriting your `split` function into something more general which also works with the termination check:

```
open import Data.List
open import Data.Product
open import Function

splitBy : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (A → Bool) → List A → List (List A)
splitBy {A = A} p = uncurry′ _∷_ ∘ foldr step ([] , [])
  where
    step : A → List A × List (List A) → List A × List (List A)
    step x (cur , acc) with p x
    ... | true  = x ∷ cur , acc
    ... | false = []      , cur ∷ acc
```

Also, `stringToℕ ""` should most likely be `nothing`, unless you really want:

```
stringListToℕ "1,,2" ≡ just (1 ∷ 0 ∷ 2 ∷ [])
```

Let's rewrite it a bit (note that `helper` is your original `stringToℕ` function):

```
stringToℕ : List Char → Maybe ℕ
stringToℕ []   = nothing
stringToℕ list = helper list 0
  where {- ... -}
```

And now we can put it all together. For simplicity I'm using `List Char` everywhere, sprinkle with `fromList`/`toList` as necessary):

```
let x1 = s                   : List Char        -- start
let x2 = splitBy notComma x1 : List (List Char) -- split at commas
let x3 = map stringToℕ x2    : List (Maybe ℕ)   -- map our ℕ-conversion
let x4 = sequence x3         : Maybe (List ℕ)   -- turn Maybe inside out
```

You can find `sequence` in `Data.List`; we also have to specify which monad instance we want to use. `Data.Maybe` exports its monad instance under the name `monad`. Final code:

```
open import Data.Char
open import Data.List
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Nat
open import Function

stringListToℕ : List Char → Maybe (List ℕ)
stringListToℕ = sequence Data.Maybe.monad ∘ map stringToℕ ∘ splitBy notComma
```

And a small test:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

test : stringListToℕ ('1' ∷ '2' ∷ ',' ∷ '3' ∷ []) ≡ just (12 ∷ 3 ∷ [])
test = refl
```

---

Considering your second question: there are many ways to turn a `Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ))` into a `Maybe (List ℕ)`, for example:

```
silly : Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ)) → Maybe (List ℕ)
silly _ = nothing
```

Right, this doesn't do much. We'd like the conversion to preserve the elements if they are all `just`. `isNothing` already does this part of checking but it cannot get rid of the inner `Maybe` layer.

`from-just` *could* work since we know that when we use it, all elements of the `List` must be `just x` for some `x`. The problem is that `conv` in its current form is just wrong - `from-just` works as a function of type `Maybe A → A` only when the `Maybe` value is `just x`! We could very well do something like this:

```
test₂ : Maybe (List ℕ)
test₂ = conv ∘ just $ nothing ∷ just 1 ∷ []
```

And since `from-list` behaves as a `Maybe A → ⊤` when given `nothing`, we are esentially trying to construct a heterogeneous list with elements of type both `⊤` and `ℕ`.

Let's scrap this solution, I'll show a much simpler one (in fact, it should resemble the first part of this answer).

We are given a `Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ))` and we gave two goals:

- take the inner `List (Maybe ℕ)` (if any), check if all elements are `just x` and in this case put them all into a list wrapped in a `just`, otherwise return `nothing`
- squash the doubled `Maybe` layer into one

Well, the second point sounds familiar - that's something monads can do! We get:

```
join : {A : Set} → Maybe (Maybe A) → Maybe A
join mm = mm >>= λ x → x
  where
    open RawMonad Data.Maybe.monad
```

This function could work with any monad but we'll be fine with `Maybe`.

And for the first part, we need a way to turn a `List (Maybe ℕ)` into a `Maybe (List ℕ)` - that is, we want to swap the layers while propagating the possible error (i.e. `nothing`) into the outer layer. Haskell has specialized typeclass for this kind of stuff (`Traversable` from `Data.Traversable`), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460809/can-someone-explain-the-traverse-function-in-haskell) has some excellent answers if you'd like to know more. Basically, it's all about rebuilding the structure while collecting the "side effects". We'll be fine with the version that works just for `List`s and we're back at `sequence` again.

There's still one piece missing, let's look at what we have so far:

```
sequence-maybe : List (Maybe ℕ) → Maybe (List ℕ)
sequence-maybe = sequence Data.Maybe.monad

join : Maybe (Maybe (List ℕ)) → Maybe (List ℕ)
  -- substituting A with List ℕ
```

We need to apply `sequence-maybe` inside one `Maybe` layer. That's where the `Maybe` functor instance comes into play (you could do it with a monad instance alone, but it's more convenient). With this functor instance, we can lift an ordinary function of type `a → b` into a function of type `Maybe a → Maybe b`. And finally:

```
open import Category.Functor
open import Data.Maybe

final : Maybe (List (Maybe ℕ)) → Maybe (List ℕ)
final mlm = join (sequence-maybe <$> mlm)
  where
    open RawFunctor functor
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer and I learn many new points about Agda and dependent type theory. It also showed me I have a long way to go! thanks again! (the delay was due to a business trip...)

Answer (score 2):

I had a go at it trying not to be clever and using simple recursive functions rather than stdlib magic. `parse xs m ns` parses `xs` by recording the (possibly empty) prefix already read in `m` while keeping the list of numbers already parsed in the accumulator `ns`.

If a parsing failure happens (non recognized character, two consecutive `,`, etc.) everything is thrown away and we return `nothing`.

```
module parseList where

open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List
open import Data.Maybe
open import Data.Char
open import Data.String

isDigit : Char → Maybe ℕ
isDigit '0' = just 0
isDigit '1' = just 1
isDigit '2' = just 2
isDigit '3' = just 3
isDigit _   = nothing

attach : Maybe ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
attach nothing  n = n
attach (just m) n = 10 * m + n

Quote : List Char → Maybe (List ℕ)
Quote xs = parse xs nothing []
  where
    parse : List Char → Maybe ℕ → List ℕ → Maybe (List ℕ)
    parse []         nothing  ns = just ns
    parse []         (just n) ns = just (n ∷ ns)
    parse (',' ∷ tl) (just n) ns = parse tl nothing (n ∷ ns)
    parse (hd ∷ tl)  m        ns with isDigit hd
    ... | nothing = nothing
    ... | just n  = parse tl (just (attach m n)) ns

stringListToℕ : String → Maybe (List ℕ)
stringListToℕ xs with Quote (toList xs)
... | nothing = nothing
... | just ns = just (reverse ns)

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

test : stringListToℕ ("12,3") ≡ just (12 ∷ 3 ∷ [])
test = refl
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Code from Vitus as a running example that uses the Agda Prelude

```
module Parse where

open import Prelude

-- Install Prelude
---- clone this git repo:
---- https://github.com/fkettelhoit/agda-prelude

-- Configure Prelude
--- press Meta/Alt and the letter X together
--- type "customize-group" (i.e. in the mini buffer)
--- type "agda2"
--- expand the Entry "Agda2 Include Dirs:"
--- add the directory 



open import Data.Product using (uncurry′)
open import Data.Maybe using ()
open import Data.List using (sequence)

splitBy : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} → (A → Bool) → List A → List (List A)
splitBy {A = A} p = uncurry′ _∷_ ∘ foldr step ([] , [])
  where
    step : A → List A × List (List A) → List A × List (List A)
    step x (cur , acc) with p x
    ... | true  = x ∷ cur , acc
    ... | false = []      , cur ∷ acc


charsToℕ : List Char → Maybe ℕ
charsToℕ []   = nothing
charsToℕ list = stringToℕ (fromList list)

notComma : Char → Bool
notComma c = not (c == ',')

-- Finally:

charListToℕ : List Char → Maybe (List ℕ)
charListToℕ = Data.List.sequence Data.Maybe.monad ∘ map charsToℕ ∘ splitBy     notComma

stringListToℕ : String → Maybe (List ℕ)
stringListToℕ = charListToℕ ∘ toList


-- Test

test1 : charListToℕ ('1' ∷ '2' ∷ ',' ∷ '3' ∷ []) ≡ just (12 ∷ 3 ∷ [])
test1 = refl

test2 : stringListToℕ "12,33" ≡ just (12 ∷ 33 ∷ [])
test2 = refl

test3 : stringListToℕ ",,," ≡ nothing
test3 = refl

test4 : stringListToℕ "abc,def" ≡ nothing
test4 = refl
```