# Trouble with Haskell GUI programming and lazy evaluation

Tags: user-interface, haskell, lazy-evaluation

In an attempt to use Haskell for a graphical application, I've had a lot of  trouble getting the GUI to evaluate in an eager fashion.

For example, I sometimes attempt to create widgets somewhere in the program, package it and send it to other components of my program.

This doesn't work out that well, usually never resulting in the widget getting displayed due to lazy evaluation discarding the widget before it gets a chance to be put on the screen.

So I wanted to know, other than putting in a bunch of `seq` and other variations to encourage eager evaluation, can/how does one deal with this issue?

I've searched for an answer, but couldn't really find anything related to this line of questioning.

EDIT: sample code

The code below produced an empty window.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}
    -- allows recursive do notation
    -- mdo
    --  ...

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import qualified Data.List       as List
import System.Random

import Graphics.UI.WX hiding (Event)
import Graphics.UI.WXCore as WXCore
import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.WX

boardWidth, boardHeight :: Int
boardWidth  = 41
boardHeight = 81

main :: IO ()
main = start tetris

tetris = do
    ff <- frame [text      := "Tetris"
                ,bgcolor   := white
                ,resizeable:= False]

    p <- panel ff []
    set ff [ layout := minsize (sz 100 100) $ widget p]

    pps <- return $ Map.fromList $ map (\l@(x,y) -> (l, button p []))
                    [(x,y) | x <- [1..(boardWidth  `div` 2)], y <- [1..(boardHeight `div` 2)]]

    -- p <- pps Map.! (1,2)

    d <- return $ map (\(x,y_m) -> y_m >>= (\y -> set ff [ color := white, layout := minsize (sz 300 300) $ widget y ])) $ Map.toList pps

    -- let networkDescription :: Moment IO ()
    return ff
```

The line `p <- pps Map.! (1,2)` results in the tile at 1, 2 to display without the proper size.

Comment: This sounds like a misdiagnosis but without any code we can't help.  I suggest you make a MCVE.

Comment: You say, "other than putting in a bunch of `seq`, how does one deal with this issue?". Have you verified that putting in a bunch of `seq` does, in fact, deal with this issue?

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now; in any case, the main issue here is that you aren't actually running the `IO` actions that add the buttons to the frame. You probably want to use `traverse` on the list, instead of `map` and `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doesn't work out that well, usually never resulting in the widget getting displayed due to lazy evaluation discarding the widget before it gets a chance to be put on the screen.

As Thomas M. DuBuisson suggests, that is a misdiagnosis: the issue here doesn't have to do with lazy evaluation (and in any case lazy evaluation wouldn't discard a value you actually tried to use). Let's have a look at the line at which you'd supposedly add the buttons to the panel:

```
d <- return $ map (\(x,y_m) ->
    y_m >>= (\y -> set ff [ color := white, layout := minsize (sz 300 300) $ widget y ]))
    $ Map.toList pps
```

The type of `Map.toList pps` is `[((Int, Int), IO (Button ())]`. Your use of `map` changes it into `[IO ()]` (cf. [the type of `set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wx-0.92.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-WX-Attributes.html#v:set)), a *list of `IO` actions*. In effect, you are setting up the actions that add the buttons, but you never actually run them. To do that, you want `traverse_` from `Data.Foldable` instead of `map`:

```
traverse_ (\(x,y_m) ->
    y_m >>= (\y -> set ff [ color := white, layout := minsize (sz 300 300) $ widget y ]))
    $ Map.toList pps
```

(For more on `traverse_` and its cousin `traverse`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460846/2751851), as well as the other answers to the parent question.)

Note that, unless I'm badly misreading the WX-specific code, *this still won't do what you want*. As each `IO` action you generate for a list element resets the layout of the frame, you'll  end up with only the last button in the frame. To get a sensible layout, you'll have to actually use the coordinate values, as well as the WX layout combinators to set up a single layout with all buttons. Cf. [the `Graphics.UI.WX.Layout` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wx-0.92.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-WX-Layout.html#v:layout).

On a final note, code like this in a do-block...

```
bar <- return foo
```

... is always redundant: it can be replaced by:

```
let bar = foo
```

In your case, doing that would have made it much more obvious that you weren't actually running the actions.

(Your uses of `Map.fromList` and `Map.toList` are also redundant, but I guess you already suspected that.)